# How can I clear the color of \title in \titlepage?

Tags: beamer, color, titles

I use the `Madrid` theme with the [`beamer` class](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) and need to customize the `\titlepage`.

The first thing is to remove the background color of the `\title` on the first page (`\titlepage`).

I searched TeX.SE and got some customized examples, but they are not what I want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}

\begin{document}

\title{(Title)}
\author{(Author)}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you. By the way. How to increase the font size of title

Comment: @pythonee Sorry, I don't know that. Please search for questions about [tag:beamer], [tag:titles], and [tag:fontsize] and, if none is helpful, ask a new one.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to keep the rounded box, try something like:

```
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=white,fg=blue}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}

\title{My title}
\author{My name}
\institute{My institute}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=white,fg=blue}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

> **EDIT**

I've seen that in one comment you asked how to increase the title font. Here is a MWE that does it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}

\title{My title}
\author{My name}
\institute{My institute}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}
\setbeamerfont*{title}{size=\huge}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Graphical result:

[image]

Comment: I dont want to keep the box

Comment: Sorry, but you did not specified this aspect in your question :)

Comment: @pythonee: I edited my answer to insert the example to increase the title font.